# How to assign for loop counter in each step to a dataframe column as a value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

how to assign for loop counter as a value of datagram column for each loop in an existing data frame

```
mylist = [6,29,59,89]

for x in mylist:

    df['column_name'] = x

but this does not work
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK0UQ.png)

Comment: use enumerate to get loop counter

Comment: So you want to count elements?

Comment: How to use enumerate

Comment: No, I want to assign  ioop counter as a value to dataframe column like picture